# how to hide path displayed on hover effect of anchor tag

Tags: jquery, html

I have used action link in anchor tag to download uploaded file,
 as below -

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("DownloadFiles", "Document", new { id = doc.Id, moduleName = ModuleName })" >@doc.Name</a>
```

but on hover effect it shows

```
Documents/DownloadFiles/3?moduleName=abc
```

here DOcument is controller name, DownloadFiles is method name , 3 is document Id and abc is module name.

I want jquery or html code to hide this path displayed on hover effect.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `window.open()` method instead of direct link. Like,

```
<a onclick="window.open('@Url.Action("DownloadFiles", "Document", new { id = doc.Id, moduleName = ModuleName })','newWindow','');">@doc.Name</a>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

That is browser feature you cannot hide that unless you cannot give href attribute.

You can achieve that by hide anchor tag and put `<div id="hide_href">@doc.Name</div>` then write click event function. In that function trigger click to your anchor tag.